# Django Admin inline for recursive ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm

I have the following model with a many-to-many relationship to itself

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        (0, "Open"),
        (1, "Closed"),
    )
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0,choices=STATUS)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    replies = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    description = models.TextField()
```

i am trying to display this model as an inline in the admin, using the following code

```
class TicketReply(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ticket.replies.through
```

however i keep getting this error

```
<class 'tsn.ticket.models.Ticket_replies'> has more than 1 ForeignKey to <class 'tsn.ticket.models.Ticket'>
```

so im i doing this wrong, or is this not supported ?

Comment: fk_name and related_name are settings you should check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model

Comment: i keep getting the same error, even after adding the related_name setting, and when adding fk_name it says 'TicketReply.fk_name' refers to field 'replies' that is missing from model 'Ticket_replies', i don't think that this is supported because looking at the source code, when validating the inline django expects a Foreignkey

Comment: You should post the Ticket_replies model as well

Answer (score 26):

May be its' to late, but I try answer this question. Ticket.replies.through is a table to manage many-to-many relations, it has fields from_ticket and to_ticket(FK to model Ticket) and you can set this fields as option fk_name for TabularInline.

```
class TicketReply(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ticket.replies.through
    fk_name = 'from_ticket'
```

Comment: That `fk_name` is the magic for the recursive definition! Thank you!

Comment: I know this is very old but still a long shot. How can I get the fields of the inline to be editable in a manytomany relationship to itself?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I was facing the same issue until I saw this. The documentation threw me off because it states that the generated field(s) name for a through table for a recursive relationship are to_<model>_id and from_<model>_id but it didn't work until I saw your answers which didn't specify any '_id' suffix for the 'fk_name'